# ASP.NET vNext Project Reference

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core

Does anybody know how to add `project reference` in `ASP.NET` vNext?

**project.json**

```
{
    "dependencies": {
        "myProject":  ""
    },
    "configurations" : {
        "net45" : { },
        "k10" : { }
    }
}
```

It doesn't work :(

Comment: Where is "myProject" relative to this project.json? You might have to explicitly say where the source is, like here: https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/dev/global.json

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've found the solution.

1. You can use only ASP.NET vNext projects (I tried to use "Class library", but it works only with "ASP.NET vNext Classs Library"
2. You should use global.json to declare your folders.

Comment: Where did you find "ASP.NET vNext Class Library"?

Answer (score 0):

when you save the project.json file,the References node in Solution Explorer shows the class library project and identifies it as a project in the properties window (other references such as Helios show up as NuGet package references).

if can not,you can try restart the vs